# Bottom Navigation view is not detecting item selected

Tags: kotlin, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

Im trying to make a bottom navigation view to control which fragment is displayed but the navigation view didn't detect any item selected. Here is my Activity Code :

```
val fragmentMore = MoreMenuFragment()
    val fragmentTransactionHistory = TransactionHistoryFragment()
    val fragmentLicenseList = DaftarLisensiFragment()

    replaceFragment(fragmentTransactionHistory)

    binding.mainNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.menuTransactionHistoryFragment -> replaceFragment(fragmentTransactionHistory)
            R.id.menuLicenseListFragment -> replaceFragment(fragmentLicenseList)
            R.id.menuMoreFragment -> replaceFragment(fragmentMore)
        }
        true
    }
```

Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".presentation.view.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/second_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:subtitle="Management System"
    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
    app:title="LeleStacia Store"
    app:titleMarginTop="5dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/fourth_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mainNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/second_color"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuTransactionHistoryFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
    android:title="Riwayat Transaksi"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuLicenseListFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_storage"
    android:title="Daftar Lisensi"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuMoreFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
    android:title="More"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</menu>
```

I also put the log before to check if the navigation item got selected or not, but my function did not get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have your "replaceFragment" function so here's how it should look like :

```
private fun replaceFragment(Check: Int, context: Context) {
            //val frg: Fragment? = null
            val fragment: Fragment
            if(Check == 0)
                fragment = FirstFragment(this)
            else if(Check == 1) {
                fragment = SecondFragment(this)
            }else if(Check == 2) {
                fragment = ThirdFragment(this)
            }else{
                fragment = FirstFragment(this)
            }
            val repo = Repository()
            repo.YourRepoFunc{
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.attach(fragment)
                transaction.commit()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I forgot to include attach to my function